# RN Documentation for Troubleshooting MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, documentation, push-notification

For my question ref to [push notification not received](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366371/push-notification-not-delivered-sfmc-to-fcm/366466#366466), Bill mentioned that I may have
failed to follow the multiple push provider implementation instructions (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html). I checked out the documentation and I believe its for Android Native, by chance, is there a ReactNative documentation/implementation for this ?

Comment: You must write native classes for this.  There is no other way.  From the documentation provided, you can probably just cut & paste the code into whatever messaging receiver/service your other provider has.

Comment: Thanks @BillMote. This is my first time integrating, but I want to clarify when you say "multiple push providers" does it mean if we integrated other push providers ? I believe we are only using firebase.

Comment: You are using Firebase to send push notifications in addition to the Marketing Cloud?  That is still "multiple push providers".

Comment: Alright, thanks @BillMote. Will look into this.